# xpath for missing node

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following xml:

```
<root>
  <node>
     <tag1/>
     <tag2/>
     <tag3/>
  </node>
  <node>
     <tag1/>
     <tag2/>
     <tag3/>
  </node>
  <node>
     <tag1/>
     <tag3/>
  </node>
</root>
```

As you can see, in the 3rd node I have a missing `tag2`. Is there any xpath I can apply to a c# XmlDocument (via SelectNodes) that can return me the node that does not have the `tag2` node?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try the following xpath:

```
/root/node[not(tag2)]
```