# Select all nodes with empty or missing child nodes

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Given the below XML:

```
<books>
    <book>
        <author>Tom</author>
        <genres>
            <genre>Science</genre>
            <genre>Romance</genre>
        </genres>
    </book>
    <book>
       <author>Mary</author>
    </book>
    <book>
        <author>Mike</author>
        <genres>
            <genre>Politics</genre>
            <genre>Romance</genre>
        </genres>
    </book>
    <book>
       <author>Susan</author>
       <genres />
    </book>
</books>
```

I cannot seem to find an XPath that will return all books that do not have a genre defined (ie Mary and Susan).  I've done a lot of testing and this empty child test is throwing me.  My latest non-working attempt was:

```
/books/book[genres/*[count(*)=0]]
```

Please note that Susan's book has a "genres" node but it has no children while Mary's doesn't even have this.   Maybe this is just too complex to work through XPath.   I'd be happy if I could just solve one condition or the other if combining both are not possible.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12581128/2704659

Comment: How the heck did I not find that?  I spent like 2 hours looking here before I posted.  Thanks rory!!  That did it.  You should post that as an answer that I can accept.

Comment: no problem, you're welcome.  I think that makes this question a dupe, though, so really it should be deleted or else it will be closed as a dupe.

Comment: @rory.ap why do you hint that closing as duplicate is bad in some way? The only marginally problematic part of this question is "does not work" could be a bit more specific... Otherwise look like good search target for the problem.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov -- I never thought of it that way.  Usually closed questions get deleted as a matter of course, but now that I think about it that's if they're down voted and have no up-voted answers.  I never thought of dupe questions being a sign post to direct people to other questions.  So I take it back Jon, I wouldn't delete.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov, I was actually trying to keep the search criteria in mind while I was formulating my question.   I use Stack Overflow a lot and missing common search terms has always been a pet peeve of mine.  Hopefully this will point people to the found solution quicker.

Comment: @JonGlazer Your attempt using `count()` with a bit of modification should also work : `/books/book[count(genres/*)=0]]`